# How to update by taking values from textboxes on windows form in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to take the values from textboxes on a windows form and then update the values in the sql server database...I want to update only those fields for which a value has been entered by the user and leave the fields for which the textboxes are left empty by the user.....How can I generate the query dynamically for such a situation???

Edit:

I haven't yet coded for the update option...Here is my insertion code and i wanted to implement the update feature the same way just couldn't figure out how i can generate the query dynamically....It's a Booking System application

```vb
        Dim str As String  ' defines str as a string variable

        'takes insertion query as a string in str variable
        str = "Insert into Bookings  Values(@cust_id, @cust_name,@contact, @game, @courtno, @poolno, @tableno, @booking_date, @booking_time, @booking_duration)"

        'defines a new command which takes query string and connection string as parameters
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(str, con)

        ' defines Customer ID parameter and takes its value from the form 
        Dim prmCustID As New SqlParameter("@cust_id", SqlDbType.Char)
        prmCustID.Value = MskdTxtCustId.Text

        ' defines Customer Name parameter and takes its value from the form 
        Dim prmCustName As New SqlParameter("@cust_name", SqlDbType.Char)
        prmCustName.Value = TxtCustName.Text

        ' defines Contact parameter and takes its value from the form 

        Dim prmContact As New SqlParameter("@contact", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        prmContact.Value = MskdTxtCntctno.Text

        ' defines Game parameter and takes its value from the form 

        Dim prmGame As New SqlParameter("@game", SqlDbType.Char)
        prmGame.Value = TxtGame.Text

        ' defines Court No parameter and takes its value from the form 

        Dim prmCrtNo As New SqlParameter("@courtno", SqlDbType.Int)
        If TxtCrtNo.Text = "" Then
            prmCrtNo.Value = Convert.DBNull     'If the textbox is empty then places Null in databse field
        Else
            prmCrtNo.Value = CType(TxtCrtNo.Text, Integer)  ' converts from string to integer
        End If
        ' defines Pool No parameter and takes its value from the form 

        Dim prmPoolNo As New SqlParameter("@poolno", SqlDbType.Int)
        If TxtPoolNo.Text = "" Then
            prmPoolNo.Value = Convert.DBNull    'If the textbox is empty then places Null in databse field
        Else
            prmPoolNo.Value = CType(TxtPoolNo.Text, Integer)    ' converts from string to integer

        End If

        ' defines Table No parameter and takes its value from the form 

        Dim prmTblNo As New SqlParameter("@tableno", SqlDbType.Int)
        If TxtTblNo.Text = "" Then
            prmTblNo.Value = Convert.DBNull     'If the textbox is empty then places Null in databse field
        Else
            prmTblNo.Value = CType(TxtTblNo.Text, Integer)  ' converts from string to integer
        End If

        ' defines Booking Date parameter and takes its value from the form 

        Dim prmBookDate As New SqlParameter("@booking_date", SqlDbType.DateTime)
        prmBookDate.Value = TxtBookDate.Text

        ' defines Booking Time parameter and takes its value from the form 

        Dim prmBookTime As New SqlParameter("@booking_time", SqlDbType.DateTime)
        prmBookTime.Value = TxtBookTime.Text

        ' defines Booking Duration parameter and takes its value from the form 

        Dim prmBookDur As New SqlParameter("@booking_duration", SqlDbType.Int)
        prmBookDur.Value = CType(TxtBookDur.Text, Integer)


        'Command cmd takes all the parameters

        cmd.Parameters.Add(prmCustID)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prmCustName)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prmContact)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prmGame)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prmCrtNo)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prmBookDate)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prmBookTime)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prmBookDur)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prmPoolNo)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prmTblNo)


        Dim str1 As String  ' defines string variable for taking select query


        str1 = "select bookingID from Bookings"     'takes select query in string variable for retrieving booking ID from the databse

        Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand(str1, con)    'defines a new command which takes query string and connection string as parameters
        Dim x As Integer                        ' defines an integer for storing booking ID

        con.Open()                               'sets the connection state to open
        Using (con)                              'specifies the connection which is to be used by the SQLcommands

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()                'Executes the insertion query

            Dim id As SqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()      'Defines and initiates the datareader to read data from database using cmd1 command
            While id.Read()                                     'Iterates the reader to read booking id
                x = id("bookingID")                             'stores the booking Id in variable x
            End While
            id.Close()
        End Using
        con.Close()                                             'sets the connection state to close

        ' shows message box with successful booking message
        MessageBox.Show("New booking saved successfully" & vbCrLf & "Your Booking ID is " & x, "Saved Successfully", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a very broad question and highly dependend on what type of data-access framework your are going to use.

You could go low-level and use SqlCommand (if you use MsSql) or OdbcCommand to wrap up all with a SQL Update statement, with setters only for the fields you changed.

You could do dataset/datatable/dataadapter, load the row change only the fields you changed and update the table again.

You could do the same with LingToSql or EF.

If you want details please tell us what you tried and what you want to use.

Comment: I'm trying SqlCommand and pass the textbox values as parameters to the Sql command

Comment: ok - can you post your code so far? But I would advise going DataSet or Linq2Sql instead - it's easier and it's more secure.

Comment: The main thing i want to know is that how can i keep track of which textboxes' values have changed and based on that how can i generate the query string dynamically

Comment: either you *remember* the values at load time (just copy them into another variable/field) or you reload the data from the database again - your choice. If you use one of the later options I gave you the reloading is allready there so this is the best option.

Comment: Or you can go MVVM or a similar pattern and just set a updated-flag if a property of your (view)model has changed ...

Comment: I think you are not getting my point....I'm saying that say there are 5 textboxes on the form and the user has changed the values of 2 of them...I can keep track of that...Now when i write the query as a general thing i can write "Update tablename set " and after that the column names and values should be concatenated to this general string and i want an optimized code i.e. a short one to add the column name and textbox value to this general string

Comment: sure you could do this but string-concatination with user-input is a No-Go (Sql-Injection) and I honestly don't want to show you how to get yourself into deep trouble. I suggest using DataTable/Adapter (very easy and with designer-support) or learn about the MVVM or MVP pattern and do this. But  at 5 textboxes the first option will be good enough even if you have to copy a line 5 times ... show some code and I might help further.

Comment: I haven't coded for the dataadapter as yet....However i'm pasting the complete insertion code here and i wanted to implement the update the same way just didn't know how could i generate query dynamically....It's actually a booking system application..

Comment: The point of using an [Object-Relational Mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Relational_Mapping), as Carsten is suggesting, is that *you don't need to create a query string*. The underlying framework does that for you.